# How can I check if the href path contain image or someother link using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Any One Know Tell me the suggestion to do this. How can i check if the anchor href attribute contain image path or some other path.

**For Example:**

```
    <a href="image.jpg"><img src="image.jpg"/></a>
    <a href="http://google.com"><img src="image.jpg"/></a>
```

See the above example shows href attribute contain different path like first one is the image and second one is the some other site link. I still confuse with that how can i check if the href path contain the image path or some other path using jquery or javascript.

Any suggestion would be great.

Comment: How are you getting the anchor element that you want to test?

Comment: `~[...].indexOf(a.href.slice(-3))` would be a reasonable approximation if `a` points to the anchor element.

Comment: I want to check it dynamically for every image. If the href attribute contain image path then i going to do something like

Comment: I mean, do you have a reference to the anchor element? A reference to its jQuery wrapper? Only an HTML string containing it?

Comment: Also, are you trying to do this client-side or server-side?  If client-side, why was it tagged PHP?

Comment: Just looking to see if a file has .jpg, .png or .gif extension isn't really enough to prove that the file is or isn't an image, especially when checking links.

Comment: Thanks, reason i am tagged is the way to do in php(server side). I am try first on client and if not i go for server.

Comment: @BrianHoover checking the extension is the closest you can get without actually visiting the URL

Comment: @JanDvorak - Completely agree, just pointing out that this will never give a definitive answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example (you may need to include other pic formats if needed):

```
$("a").each(function(i, el) {
  var href_value = el.href;
  if (/\.(jpg|png|gif)$/.test(href_value)) {
     console.log(href_value + " is a pic");
  } else {
     console.log(href_value + " is not a pic");
  }
});
```

Comment: umm... I think you wanted to escape the period in the regex

Comment: `$(el).attr("href");` is quite suboptimal. Why not use `el.href` instead?

Comment: The reason [I call this an approximation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563852/how-can-i-check-if-the-href-path-contain-image-or-someother-link-using-javascrip#comment25552231_17563852): `http://example.jpg is a pic` `http://example.com/picture.tiff is not a pic`. While a `.jpg` or `.png` top-level domain is unlikely to happen, if somebody decides to use in image format like `.com` (ok, this one is already an executable) or `.cx` (there's already `.pcx`), then you've got a problem ;-)

Comment: Yes, I understand that. One can put a pic into `.txt` file and not a pic into `.png` one.

Comment: Also, that. But I was pointing out you mix up together file extensions (which are supposed to describe the content type) with top-level domains (which don't have much to do with content)

Answer (score 1):

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  var checkhref = $('a').attr('href');
  var image_check = checkhref.substr(checkhref.length - 4)
  http_tag = "http";
  image = [".png",".jpg",".bmp"]
  if(checkhref.search("http_tag") >= 0){
    alert('Http!');
    //Do something
  }
  if($.inArray(image_check, image) > -1){
    alert('Image!');
    //Do something
  }
});
```

Comment: What if the image is an absolute url?

Comment: @Brian If href path contain similar to this http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png then what is to be happen ?

Comment: Edited to see if it fits your specifications better.

Answer (score 1):

you may check if image exists or not, without jQuery

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WWFnD/1/)

```
 var imagesrc = 'http://domain.com/image.jpg';
function checkImage(src) {
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("iddiv").innerHTML = src +" exists";

};
img.onerror = function() {
    document.getElementById("iddiv").innerHTML = src +"does not exists";
};
img.src = src; // fires off loading of image
return src;
}
checkImage(imagesrc);
```

Comment: Nice idea, but it's an attack vector for [cross-source request forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Csrf) depending on the URL source